# I can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm getting this message in error console:

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Cannot modify properties of a WrappedNative"  
nsresult: "0x80570034 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CANT_MODIFY_PROP_ON_WN)"  location: "JS frame :: 
chrome://global/content/bindings/autocomplete.xml :: onxblpopuphiding :: line 834"  data: no]
```

I checked everything I've possibly can, but I don't see what's wrong! I tried clearing cache, 3 times. I tested on a second computer, and it still doesn't work. **Edit:** It shows the data for one second or so and then disappears.

Comment: Can you cange the title of your question so it describes the problem? E.g. Vaules disappear seconds after post. Thanks

Comment: In addition, since you removed the link to your page, it might be useful for other SO users to post a brief section from your HTML and JavaScript. You may remove all the parts that are not related to the question and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values were disappearing because the submit button is posting the form and therefore refreshing the page. Simply change:

```
<input type='submit' value='Submit' onclick='process()'>
```

to:

```
<input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='process()'>
```

... and the data will not disappear when you click the button.

An `<input type="button">` defines a clickable button, that does not automatically submit the form when clicked. In fact this button type is often used to call a JavaScript function through the `onClick` event, as you were doing in your web page.

As for the uncaught exception, this is probably related to a browser plugin, as [Sarfraz Ahmed suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216531/i-cant-figure-out-whats-wrong/2216545#2216545).

Answer (score 1):

I saw your page, and for me it did not generate the error you have shown. This must be the firefox addon related error. As you can see from the path too:

```
chrome://global/content/bindings/autocomplete.xml
```

There must be something else going on with it i suspect.